# Outbound call using Twilio client on ipad or iphone not working

Tags: twilio

So I'm trying to use the demo on http://www.twilio.com/client and it's not working on an iphone 5 or ipad mini. When I dial a number using Safari on an iphone or ipad, this is what happens...

1. A label "Calling..." shows up under the text field
2. The phone number I entered rings as expected
3. I pick up the phone and all I hear is the hold music - it's as though the ipad/iphone never knows that I've picked up the phone on the receiving end.

If I try the same thing using IE9 on a desktop, it works fine and I can hear both sides of the audio fine.

Can someone please confirm that it's supposed to work on iphone/ipad??? Thx!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, on http://www.twilio.com/help/faq/twilio-client/what-are-the-minimum-system-requirements-for-twilio-client, the browser must support Flash. It will use WebRTC if available, but fall back to Flash for the connections. The connect/disconnect sounds require Flash.

I'm surprised that it even partially worked for you; we had no luck at all. When I go to the test page (http://clientsupport.twilio.com) with an iPad, it says that both the browser and Flash support (duh!) failed.